# How to apply DebuggerDisplay attribute to Enum?

Tags: c#, enums

**Problem**: I would like to use Enum of string type.

I have an extension method that returns string values based on my Enum. But also, the extension supports registering new values which come from the database or as input from Web API.

So, the use case of the enum is to have predefined constants which I can use in my code for specific cases.


Full example available here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BFkkd7

```
var pdf = FileExtensionEnum.PDF;
Console.WriteLine(pdf);                         //Output: "PDF"
Console.WriteLine(pdf.ToExtensionString());     //Output: ".pdf"

var newExtension = (FileExtensionEnum)10;
Console.WriteLine(newExtension);                         //Output: 10
Console.WriteLine(newExtension.ToExtensionString());     //Output: "10"
            
var registeredFile = ".png".FromStringExtension();
Console.WriteLine(registeredFile);                         //Output: 4
Console.WriteLine(registeredFile.ToExtensionString());     //Output: ".png"
```

But, in the debbuger it will look like this:
[image: Enum variable in debugger]

**newExtension** variable holds value "10" and will be display as 10 because it is unknown value for *FileExtensionEnum* and it is unknown value for my extenions method.

**registeredFile** value is unknowm for *FileExtensionEnum* and will be displayed as **4**, but my extension will display it as **".png"**


The remaining part, is to force debugger display *FileExtensionEnum* using my extension method. So, it will be always displayed as a string.

Below what I have tried to do for Visual Studio 2022.

###### Idea 1 - Override ToString()

But it is not possbile for Enum type.

###### Idea 2 - DebuggerDisplayAttribute

I've tried to use DebuggerDisplayAttribute in multiple ways.

Any of those lines gives the same result:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Value = {this.ToExtensionString()}")]
[DebuggerDisplay("Value = {EnumToString.EnumStringExtension.ToExtensionString(this)}")]
[DebuggerDisplay("Value = {this}")]
[DebuggerDisplay("Value = {GetValue()}")]

[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("Value = {EnumToString.EnumStringExtension.ToExtensionString(this)}", Target = typeof(EnumToString.FileExtensionEnum))]

// result
pdf Value = <Internal Error evaluating expression>  EnumToString.FileExtensionEnum
```

[image]

###### Idea 3 - DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute

```
public class EnumStringDebugView
{
    private readonly FileExtensionEnum value;
    public EnumStringDebugView(FileExtensionEnum value) => this.value = value;
    public override string ToString() => value.ToExtensionString();
}

// Compilation time error:
// CS0592   Attribute 'DebuggerTypeProxy' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'assembly, class, struct' declarations.
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(EnumStringDebugView))]
public enum FileExtensionEnum

// Does not fail, but just ignored
[assembly: DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(EnumToString.EnumStringDebugView), Target = typeof(EnumToString.FileExtensionEnum))]
```

###### Idea 4 - Use custom class with static readonly strings

Yes, I can define my own class with a static readonly fields. But, it is not possible to use it as a default value for optional paramters. With Enum - you can.

```
public class SampleStringCode
{
    private string readonly _value;
    private SampleStringCode(string value) => this._value = value;

    public static readonly SampleStringCode S1 = new("S1");
    public static readonly SampleStringCode S2 = new("S2");
    public static readonly SampleStringCode S3 = new("S3");
}
```

###### Idea 5 - String constants

Yeah, we can simply use string constants and this is my current solution.

But, as a new developer - I don't know where we have those constants I can use for that specific property.

Enum and custom class solves that problem, but have other problems.

###### Idea 6 - Custom Code Analyzer

If we have a class with string constants:

```
public static class FileExtenions
{
    public const string EXCEL = ".excel";
    public const string PDF = ".pdf";
    public const string JPG = ".jpg";
}
```

Then we can have a custom attribute we can apply to a string property or string parameter.

```
public class Document
{
    [UseConst(typeof(FileExtenions))]
    public string Extension { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement a custom code analyzer which based on the attribute restricts you to assing any string to the property except constants from *FileExtenions* class.

I didn't try to do that, but sounds like overkill. But it would be the best in terms of code simplicity. No need to write extra code, no need to write a custom EF convertors or JSON convertors or ModelBinding for API. But you have to use custom attribute.

So, **how to apply DebuggerDisplayAttribute to Enum** in VisualStudio 2022?

Comment: I hit the same wall (but with complex bitflags, no "external enums"). No solution so far.